# How to make seadragon js work with AWS S3 presigned URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, openseadragon

I am trying to get openseadragon js to work with images stored inside of my AWS S3 bucket. The files are private and I am unsure of how to go about referencing the folder that contains all my pyramid images. In the tilesource-custom [documentation](https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-custom/), they used:

```js
OpenSeadragon({
    id:            "example-custom-tilesource",
    prefixUrl:     "/openseadragon/images/",
    navigatorSizeRatio: 0.25,
    wrapHorizontal:     true,
    tileSources:   {
        height: 512*256,
        width:  512*256,
        tileSize: 256,
        minLevel: 8,
        getTileUrl: function( level, x, y ){
            return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" +
                    (level-8) + "-r" + y + "-c" + x + ".jpg";
        }
    }
});
```

I am not sure how the function(level, x, y) in getTileUrl works. I am assuming that it iterates up to a certain point. Any explanation of how it works would really help. So based on this example I tried the following:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const s3_bucket_url_js = function($key) {

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: "g-deliverables",
            Expires: 60*30,
            Key: $key,
    }, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
         console.log(err);
     } else {
         console.log(typeof url);
         return url;

     }

    });
}


OpenSeadragon({
    id:            "openseadragon1",
    prefixUrl:     "/GTSS/assets/buttons",
        showNavigator: false,
    tileSources:   {
        type: 'zoomifytileservice',
        height: 3600,
        width:  2700,
        tileSize: 256,
            getTileUrl: function( level, x, y ){
            var url_s = "whatever/pyr/some#/01_VISUAL/TileGroup0/" +level + "-" + x + "-" + y + ".jpg";
            return s3_bucket_url_js(url_s);
        }
    }
});
```

I used the AWS sdk version 2 for JS. I created a function that takes in the bucket key as an argument and then put this function called s3_bucket_url_js inside of the getTileUrl function (level, x, y). Since I don't know how function(level, x, y) works exactly I assumed that it iterated to the min-level and so I made it create my jpg filenames which follow a three digit naming convention: 0-0-0.jpg, 1-0-0.jpg, 1-1-0.jpg, etc. I think put this entire key value into my s3_bucket_url function to create a presigned url which I returned hoping it would successfully render. And of course it did not.

My folder structure in the s3 bucket is as follows:

[folder structure s3 bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3MaN.png)

When I had files stored on my ec2, I simply referenced tilesUrl: 'gtss/pyr/103/01_VISUAL/ instead of  getTileUrl and it worked fine in compiling all the images. But I am unable to reference the file folder on the s3 bucket since it is private.

Finally in the html I have added the div tag for the openseadragon map to display.

```html
<div id="openseadragon1" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Quick update: I have looked at the openseadragon.min.js file that I am using and believe I found the function getTileUrl that returns the path to each of my pyramid images. It is as follows:

```js
    _calculateAbsoluteTileNumber: function(e, t, i) {
            var n = 0;
            var o = {};
            for (var r = 0; r < e; r++) n += (o = this.gridSize[r]).x * o.y;
            return n += (o = this.gridSize[e]).x * i + t
        },
        supports: function(e, t) {
            return e.type && "zoomifytileservice" == e.type
        },
        configure: function(e, t) {
            return e
        },
        getTileUrl: function(e, t, i) {
            var n;
            var o = this._calculateAbsoluteTileNumber(e, t, i);
            n = Math.floor(o / 256);
            return this.tilesUrl + "TileGroup" + n + "/" + e + "-" + t + "-" + i + ".jpg"
        }
```

Right now I am thinking of trying to use my s3_bucket_url_js function inside of the getTileUrl method and returning s3_bucket_url_js(this.tilesUrl + "TileGroup" + n+ "/" + e + "-" + t + "-" + i + ".jpg"

There was a comment earlier about calling the presigned url from the backend and passing it to the front end. How would I go about this so I can use the s3_bucket_url_js() inside of the openseadragon.min.js file?

This is the un-minified version of the code snippet:

```js
  //private
        _calculateAbsoluteTileNumber: function(level, x, y) {
            var num = 0;
            var size = {};

            //Sum up all tiles below the level we want the number of tiles
            for (var z = 0; z < level; z++) {
                size = this.gridSize[z];
                num += size.x * size.y;
            }
            //Add the tiles of the level
            size = this.gridSize[level];
            num += size.x * y + x;
            return num;
        },

        /**
         * Determine if the data and/or url imply the image service is supported by
         * this tile source.
         * @function
         * @param {Object|Array} data
         * @param {String} optional - url
         */
        supports: function(data, url) {
            return (data.type && "zoomifytileservice" == data.type);
        },

        /**
         *
         * @function
         * @param {Object} data - the raw configuration
         * @param {String} url - the url the data was retrieved from if any.
         * @return {Object} options - A dictionary of keyword arguments sufficient
         *      to configure this tile sources constructor.
         */
        configure: function(data, url) {
            return data;
        },

        /**
         * @function
         * @param {Number} level
         * @param {Number} x
         * @param {Number} y
         */
        getTileUrl: function(level, x, y) {
            //console.log(level);
            var result = 0;
            var num = this._calculateAbsoluteTileNumber(level, x, y);
            result = Math.floor(num / 256);
            return this.tilesUrl + 'TileGroup' + result + '/' + level + '-' + x + '-' + y + '.jpg';

        }
```

Comment: You need the backend to generate the presigned URL and pass it to the frontend, otherwise your AWS keys and secrets will be leaked.

Comment: okay but it looks like I have to create the presigned URL after openseadragon creates a path to each pyramid image. I looked at the source code of openseadragon.min.js and it looks like this: 
        getTileUrl: function(e, t, i) {
            var n;
            var o = this._calculateAbsoluteTileNumber(e, t, i);
            n = Math.floor(o / 256);
            return this.tilesUrl + "TileGroup" + n + "/" + e + "-" + t + "-" + i + ".jpg"
        }
    })  (end of code snippet). I am trying to add my s3_bucket_url_js function on the return of this.tilesUrl + etc. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

So far we have figured out how to put output the s3 presigned url through the js browser. We have used aws cognito identity pool id in place of the aws secret access key to allow us to use the aws sdk js in the browser. By modifying the openseadragon.min.js file we use, we were able to put presigned urls for the pictures. In around line 5370 there is a getTileUrl function that compiles the folder path for zoomify pyramids:

```
  getTileUrl: function(e, t, i) {
        var n;
        var o = this._calculateAbsoluteTileNumber(e, t, i);
        n = Math.floor(o / 256);
        var url = this.tilesUrl + "TileGroup" + n + "/" + e + "-" + t + "-" + i + ".jpg";
        return s3_bucket_url_js(url);


    }
```

At the very last statement we placed a return with our function (located in the same file where we put the map div) and it returns a presigned url that is able to be compiled. If you notice the var url = this.titleUrl etc. The this.tilesUrl is found in the OpenSeadragon() object :

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
                  id:            "openseadragon1",
                  prefixUrl:     "assets/buttons/",
                  showNavigator: false,
tileSources:   {
          type: 'zoomifytileservice',
          height: 3600,
          width:  3600,
          tileSize: 256,
          tilesUrl: 'whatever/pyr/our path up to TileGroup#/'});
```

And here is the s3 function we used (also note we used aws sdk version 2 for browser). For us at least, calling the s3.getSignedUrl() asynchronously did not work so we had to use the synchronous way which is shown below:

```
   AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: 'your own identity pool' });
   const s3 = new AWS.S3();
   function s3_bucket_url_js(key) {
       var params = {Bucket: 'bucket name', Key: key, Expires:1000};
       var s3_presigned = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
       return s3_presigned;
       }
```

Also note the Identity Pool is for unauthenticated users. We added a s3 read only access IAM policy to the role attached to the Identity Pool. In our s3 bucket which closed to the public we added CORS policy:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "your site"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "Content-Type",
        "X-Amz-Date",
        "Authorization",
        "X-Api-Key",
        "X-Amz-Security-Token"
    ]
}
```

]

Right now, we are having some problems with the compiling. With our secret key, the OpenSeaDragon compiled all the images successfully but with the Identity Pool Id, the first 2 levels of the pyramid are not compiling and returning a non-presigned url of https://s3.amazonaws.com/ and chrome is sending CORB errors (probably because the url's are not images). I believe it has something to do with the request the browser is sending for the Identity Pool Id but we are still trying to figure out how to solve it.